# Radio Buttons: Listener in XML or JAVA?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-fragments

I decided to make an app in android for my science exhibition and I have reached a dead end!

I am trying to make a unit converter using radio buttons as the unit selection method.
All is fine but when I select another radio button, the app crashes!
I have no idea what is going on?

**Here is my XML layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/from"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/km"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="radioClicked"
        android:text="KiloMeters" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/m"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="radioClicked"
        android:text="Meters" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/cm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="radioClicked"
        android:text="Centimeters" />
</RadioGroup>

<Space
    android:id="@+id/Space1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/KmValue"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/to"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/mTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="radioClicked"
        android:text="Meters" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/cmTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="radioClicked"
        android:text="Cenitmeters" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/mmTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="radioClicked"
        android:text="Millimeters" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/MValue"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Convert" />

</TableLayout>
```

And here is my **Java Activity**:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LengthFragment extends Fragment {
    public LengthFragment(){}

    double ratio = 1000;
    int x=1;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_length, container, false);

        final EditText km = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.KmValue);
        final TextView meter = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MValue);
        Button convert = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cButton);
        convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(km.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter Something Buddy!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    float k = Float.parseFloat(km.getText().toString());
                    double m = k*ratio;
                    meter.setText(""+m);
                }
            }

        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void radioClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.km:
                if (checked)
                    x=1;
                break;
            case R.id.m:
                if (checked) {
                    x=2;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.cm:
                if (checked)
                    x=3;
                break;
            case R.id.mTo:
                if (checked)
                    if(x==1) {
                        ratio=1000;
                    }
                    else if(x==2) {
                        ratio=1;
                    }
                    else if(x==3) {
                        ratio=0.01;
                    } else {
                    }
                break;
            case R.id.cmTo:
                if (checked)
                    if(x==1) {
                        ratio=100000;
                    }
                    else if(x==2) {
                        ratio=100;
                    }
                    else if(x==3) {
                        ratio=1;
                    } else {
                    }
                break;
            case R.id.mmTo:
                if (checked)
                    if(x==1) {
                        ratio=1000000;
                    }
                    else if(x==2) {
                        ratio=1000;
                    }
                    else if(x==3) {
                        ratio=10;
                    } else {
                    }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I could post whatever may be required for the answer. Please help!

Comment: try this example and then try your code  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/RadioGroupselectionChangedListener.htm

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing OnClick to RadioButton just implement RadioGroup setOnCheckedChangeListener :

```
RadioGroup from = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.from);

from.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id) {
    if (id==R.id.km) {
        x=1;
    }else if(id==R.id.m){
        x=2;
    }else if(id==R.id.cm)
        x=3;
    }
});
```

Also apply same way setOnCheckedChangeListener for (to) RadioGroup and remove OnClick from xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a different listener for each radio group? Don't just rely on the `onClickListener()` for the Button.

Try having a [setOnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener))  for each radio group, e.g.

```
RadioGroup rgFrom = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.from);
RadioGroup rgTo = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.to);

rgFrom.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...)
rgTo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...)
```

When the callback is made, i.e. [onCheckedChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html#onCheckedChanged(android.widget.RadioGroup,%20int)), you can update your variables 'x' & 'ratio'

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
{
    switch(group.getId())
    {
        case R.id.from:
            // Do something to either 'x' or 'ratio'
            break;
        case R.id.to:
            // Do something to either 'x' or 'ratio'
            break;
    }
}
```

Refer to the links provided for more detailed information on how to use it.

You can easily do the calculation/conversion when your Button is clicked, instead of having to deal with 'x' or 'ratio'.

```
Button convert = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cButton);
convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do calculations/conversions based on the present state of the 2 radio groups
    }
});
```

Comment: I will try that but why remove the OnClick listener from xml and use the java one? XML is much neater and easier...?

Comment: In your XML, everything triggers the `onClick` function, which makes it quite messy in your code eventually. It's best to breakdown the functions into small parts, definitely much easier to design & debug in the long run, especially when your program gets bigger.